# Is bonus from Tactical Database shared with other characters/runs?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I've used [Tactical Database](http://sword-of-the-stars-the-pit.wikia.com/wiki/Tactical_Database) successfully few times, and I wonder if the bonus from it works only for current character or available in other runs too?

Cannot find any info about it on wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, bonus is for current character only!

I've found that it's actually possible to view bonuses from Tactical Database in game - it's shown when you hover over your character class.

[image: Tactical database]

I've checked my other characters and tried to create new one - they have no such bonuses.